# SEDE Sql Highlighter is borked for aliases with single quotes

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, data-explorer

I looked at [Quassnoi's latest data-explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1919/average-answerers-age-among-the-tags-answered-by-more-than-1000-users-with-age) and saw the syntax highlighting got borked because of his column alias with an apostrophe.

[image: screenshot of column alias highlighting problem]

@waffles:  I have a patch for this (which the margin is too narrow to contain) and just need to know how you want to get it.

Comment: sure email it to sam.saffron@gmail.com thanks heaps

Comment: @waffles: Sent.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood:  Does this count as "working remotely"?

Comment: Big thanks Jason, keep these bugs / features / patches coming. It makes it much easier for me to decide what to do :)

Comment: @waffles: No prob bro.  I've just been picking up the bugs I'm seeing in the client, but if you have something specific you want help with just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

fixed ages ago, upvote me so I do not get bumped anymore