# Slight issue with single quotes in code editor

Tags: support, syntax-highlighting

This is quite similar to [SEDE Sql Highlighter is borked for aliases with single quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/sede-sql-highlighter-is-borked-for-aliases-with-single-quotes) which was apparently fixed in 2010. Mine is slightly different. If you look at my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507404/sql-server-2005-database-dropped-how-to-find-out-who-did-it-when-it-happened you can see a similar issue, where delimited strings are not properly interpreted, and everything after is considered part of the string.

```sql
DECLARE @FileName VARCHAR(255)  

SELECT @FileName = SUBSTRING(path, 0, 
    LEN(path)-CHARINDEX('\', REVERSE(path))+1) + '\Log.trc' --'
  FROM sys.traces WHERE is_default = 1;  

SELECT TOP 1 LoginName, HostName, ApplicationName, StartTime, TextData
  FROM sys.fn_trace_gettable( @FileName, DEFAULT ) AS gt  
  WHERE EventClass = 47 AND DatabaseName = 'splunge'
  ORDER BY StartTime DESC;
```

I added a comment to the end of that line with a single apostrophe to avoid the rest of the code from appearing as a string, but mods please feel free to edit my answer by removing the comment to see the difference. I assume The `'\'` in the string treats the `\` as an escape character.

Not a major annoyance but the color coding is extremely useful and makes the code readable.

Comment: Did you mean to post this on Stackoverflow.com?

Comment: No, my question is about how the code editor works and incorrectly interprets a single quote as a part of the string instead of as a delimiter. Why would I post a potential bug about stack overflow to stack overflow?

Comment: The problem is that, even if you write `'\\'`, the first backslash doesn't escape the second. The behavior should depend from the language: In PHP, `'\'` would effectively escape the string delimiter, but that is not true in all the languages. (I am not sure it is so with all the SQL dialects.)

Comment: This is certainly not how it works in Transact-SQL. Perhaps we need more specific dialects than `<!-- language: lang-sql -->`?