# Please adjust syntax highlighting on SEDE to the SQL that is actually in use

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, syntax-highlighting

The highlighting on SEDE is a bit off occasionally. I've noticed that it highlights `Length` and `Concat` as function names, but the backend doesn't support those (it has `Len` and `+` instead).

Can the highlighting be tweaked to match the semantics?

Comment: When we switched CodeMirror versions, a lot of the T-SQL fixes to the highlighter got lost (read: I wasn't paying enough attention and messed up), so a lot of this is a regression. I've got a personal to-do to compare the current highlighter against the previous version to fix that, although an upcoming feature might complicate things a bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and completely redone the word lists for the various keyword/function/operator highlighters to be more representative of T-SQL. In general, what you see on Data Explorer should now be pretty consistent with what you'd see in SSMS.

The highlighter also doesn't respect T-SQL `[identifier]` escaping at the moment, which is a regression of [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51851/sede-sql-highlighter-is-borked-for-aliases-with-single-quotes). <s>I'm in the process of fixing that now.</s> I've fixed this too, and added highlighting for Data Explorer input variables (`##variable:type?default##`) for good measure.

Both fixes should go out in the next build > 2012.8.31.5, or shortly thereafter. Once they're live, let me know if you notice any remaining irregularities.